# how to make links appear when you hover out of a div in css?

Tags: css

I am having trouble changing the appearance of links when I enter a specific div. The aim was when I hovered over a specific div the links would appear in the div until i moved the mouse back out of the divs area then the links would disappear again. If someone knows the solution please feel free to answer this question.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide the code that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3):

```
div a {display:none;}
div:hover a {display:block;}
```

This hides the links when the div is not hovered. The down side of this is that this will change the height of your div when hovering. A solution is this:

```
div a {visibility:hidden;}
div:hover a {visibility:visible;}
```

Or, you could give the links the same background colour as the div and change it on hover.